# MYSQL Query to return rows BETWEEN two DATETIME fields

Tags: mysql

I have read many posts with answers concerning Mysql queries using BETWEEN none of which I can get to work with my data.
In my case, I have a data table which has two cols both of which hold data as a DateTime. I am trying to right a query that returns a row(s) of data `WHERE RoomToDateTime` is `BETWEEN` two other `DateTime` fields. Example:

```
RoomToDateTime = "2018-09-10 17:00:00"

$FromDateTime   = "2018-09-09 08:00:00" //User selected date and time
$ToDateTime     = "2018-09-10 16:00:00" //User selected date and time
```

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Conf
WHERE RoomToDateTime BETWEEN '".$FromDateTime ."' AND '".$ToDateTime."'
```

This query returns no data when I know that there is a record where RoomToDateTime does contain `"2018-09-09 10:00:00"`.

This works with dates only (excluding the time part). Can anyone see why the query does not work or am I going about this completely wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your time and helpful comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use str_to_date

```
  "SELECT * 
    FROM Conf 
    WHERE RoomToDateTime 
        BETWEEN str_to_date('".$FromDateTime ."', '%Y-%m-%d %T' )  
            AND str_to_date('".$ToDateTime."',  '%Y-%m-%d %T' )"
```

try this way with proper date time

```
  "SELECT * 
    FROM Conf 
    WHERE RoomToDateTime 
        BETWEEN str_to_date('2018-09-09 08:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T' )  
            AND str_to_date('2018-09-10 16:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T' )"
```

anyway you should not use php var ins sql string .. using these vars  you are at risk for sqlijection  ...
for avoid this take a look at your php mysql driver for prepared statements and binding param

Comment: thanks for your reply. have change the query to "SELECT *  FROM Conf WHERE  RoomToDateTime BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('".$FromDateTime ."', '%Y-%m-%d %T' ) AND STR_TO_DATE('".$ToDateTime."',  '%Y-%m-%d %T' )" but this still does not return any rows.

Comment: answer   updated  with a suggestion  (check for your real content  $fromDateTime and $toDateTime

Comment: You were right, I did have the wrong content for $fromDateTime. Thanks to yur help this now works. Again, many thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, just one issue. If the year,month and day part of the "$FromDateTime" i.e "2018-09-09" and the "$ToDateTime" is  i.e "2018-9-10" the query does not return any data, just the word "false". However, if  "$ToDateTime" i.e "2018-9-11" the query returns data. I was expecting any record where RoomToDateTime is between the "$FromDateTime"  and the "$ToDateTime".  Can you see why this would be the case.

Comment: First if you  use 2018-09-09 then you must use the proper mask  %Y-%m-%d and second if have not the time  part remember that the time ise assigned  at 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

With the date format you provided, mysql will perfectly understand the `<=` and`>=` operator. (Just to outline an option):

```
SELECT *
FROM Conf
WHERE 
   RoomToDateTime >= '".$FromDateTime ."' AND 
   RoomToDateTime <= '".$ToDateTime."'
```